# Pass Crendentials from dotNet client to Java Web Service

Tags: java, c#, web-services, jax-ws

I have a dot net application that call a java web service. I am trying to implement authentication by passing credentials to the java service. Here is the dot net code setting the credentials. How can I get these credentials in my java application? They aren't set in the headers...

```
 System.Net.NetworkCredential serviceCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
 serviceInstance.Credentials = serviceCredentials;
```

serviceInstance is an instance of SoapHttpClientProtocol.

I've tried injecting the WebServiceContext like so

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsctx;
```

and pulling the crentials from the headers but they aren't there.

Comment: You'll want to check @cleftheris' answer to see if it works, and if so, accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not passing the credentials to your service the correct way. In order to get the Authorize http request header do the following:

```
// Create the network credentials and assign
// them to the service credentials
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
Uri uri = new Uri(serviceInstance.Url);
ICredentials credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
serviceInstance.Credentials = credentials;

// Be sure to set PreAuthenticate to true or else
// authentication will not be sent.
serviceInstance.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

**Note:** Be sure to set `PreAuthenticate` to true or else authentication will not be sent. 
see this [article](http://intellitect.com/calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/) for more information.

I had to dig-up some old code for this one :)

**Update:** 
After inspecting the request/response headers using fiddler as suggested in the comments below a `WWW-Authenticate` header was missing at the Java Web Service side.

A more elegant way of implementing "JAX-WS Basic authentication" can be found in this [article here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/jax-ws-basic-authentication) using a `SoapHeaderInterceptor` (Apache CXF Interceptors)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The Authorize header is still not being set. The article says that you have to explicitly set it...is there no other way around this?

Comment: Could you inspect the http traffic using a tool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and then update your question to include the request/response headers? This would make it easier to see whether the problem lies on the client or server side

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip! I was able to compare the request/response with a previously working deployment (on weblogic - we're moving to jboss) and discovered that the "WWW-Authenticate" header was in the weblogic response. Adding that to the response manually did the trick. If you update your answer I'll mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: I do want to find a better way of getting this header to populate without having to set it manually though!